# making php based url rewriter?

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to make a `php`-based URL rewriter? I want to make a URL rewrite module for my company's CMS.

For example:

```
http://www.seacen.org/v2/content.php?id=32&lang=1.htm
```

to

```
http://www.seacen.org/v2/content/32/1
```

Comment: but when the HTTP request comes your Apache (or any other web server) is gonna innocently look inside the directory `v2/content/32/1`. It's something way before you reach PHP, I think you HAVE to use some Web Server-Based URL rewriting thingy.
I think a way around that is to have a directory for every `id` that you have in the database with an `index.php` file inside.. I mean it's stupid, but it CAN be done.

Comment: Have a look at the way that Wordpress or Expression Engine handle it; they re-write everything that's not an actual file to the one processing script. Have you looked into Mod Rewrite?

Comment: @AdnanShammout No! Don't even suggest that idea, lest somebody actually does it.

Comment: @anthony-arnold I'm not suggesting he'd actually do it, I'm just responding to the absurdity of the question. Why would anyone ever want to go that route

Comment: That's easy. Just use a .htaccess file and redirect all requests to index.php?r=RequestUrl. Then all you need to do is interpret that request. Since you didn't mention anything about not wanting to use htaccess, I assume you have confused people here by saying "php" based, when it is actually "php + apache" based

Comment: @AdnanShammout I know, I was also being a little facetious.

Comment: You can make a pure PHP version if you format the URLs like so : `http://example.com/index.php?/v2/content/2`

Comment: @Jason How do you know it's Apache? PHP can run on other web servers.

Comment: If there's a lack of information, you give the comment you think that will be most helpful. After all we are here to help people :) I think the OP just doesn't know what to ask.

Answer (score 2):

create a `.htaccess` file and paste the following inside it

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule content/(.*)/(.*)/ content.php?id=$1&lang=$2.html
```

chances are that your mod_rewrite is already enabled, but if not:

- If you're on a shared host, ask your host support to enable it for
  you.
- If you're on a VPS or running your test server locally uncomment the
  following line in your httpd.conf `LoadModule rewrite_module
  modules/mod_rewrite.s`